# How to know if teammates are in a premade squad or not?

Tags: overwatch

I know that a player in my squad is indicated in-game with a green name, but I would like to know if my other teammates are also in a squad or are solo.

That would be helpful for team communication and for coordinating attacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of [today's patch](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20747925082), a visual indicator of whether or not players are in a party are shown in the scoreboard menu:

[image]

When the players are in a party, you'll see a link between the party members within the party. In this screenshot, the enemy team has two parties, a party of 2 and a party of 3.

Comment: Excellent! Now I know who to direct my rage and flame toward when I'm upset at my teammates! (*Note: that was a joke. Please don't flame people in-game.*)

Comment: Glad to see that Blizzard add it.

Answer (score 8):

Before the game starts, you could just ask the people in your Team if there are any premades in the game. Being premade with other players means to be in a party/group with them to play together.

Most of the times, people will tell :)

Comment: yeah, that's a good point !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/186691)

Comment: @Lokuzt Technically the second sentence is a possible solution to the question.

Comment: @Lokuzt I disagree with the above comment that it doesn't answer the question. Asking the people on your team if they are in a premade (providing they answer) is the only way currently to find out if they are in a premade.

Comment: I, for one, am not familiar with this usage of the term "premade". It looks like you're using it to refer to a team/group/party.

Comment: @DCShannon Premade usually means a group *made before* matchmaking. I've seen it before in MOBA types like LoL.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Okay. In shooters (on Xbox, at least), we normally refer to that as a 'party', or maybe a 'squad'. Just pointing out that not everyone is going to be familiar with that term being used this way.

Comment: @DCShannon I actually forgot overwatch was on consoles, since blizzard has been exclusively PC far as i know up until diablo 3 at least.

Comment: @DCShannon You are right, I edited my answer to make it more clear. Thank you!

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Blizzard stared out as a console developer in the SNES era, and there's a N64 port of Starcraft, which is worse than it sounds.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I remember the original Diablo on PlayStation. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blizzard_Entertainment#Games_developed), they've released ten other games on consoles.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no labeling or way to tell if other team mates or enemy teams are part of a premade. [Here is a post](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20744984621) on the matter. One suggestion would be to keep an eye out for multiples of people joining a match at the same time, although I'm not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: Whenever a game reinstances, most people join at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Update: [As waifu says](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/278765/46216), grouped players are now indicated on the scoreboard by links between character portraits. The following still applies however.

Groups are in group voice chat by default and must join team voice chat manually. If they join team voice chat, they remain there until requeuing.

Please join team voice chat if you're in a group.

Comment: I did not realize that I was not being put in the team voice chat channel when in a group. That's good to know.

Comment: Can't you choose to not be added to a voice channel by default?

Comment: @jimrm Yes, you can do exactly that. I honestly think that the settings should be reversed- and that people are dropped in team chat automatically regardless of solo or group queuing.